# How to instrument TypeScript initialization time in a VSCode extension?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am looking to instrument TypeScript initialization performance in VSCode, similar to [the TypeTrack extension mentioned in this blog post](https://shopify.engineering/migrating-large-typescript-codebases-project-references).

Unfortunately, I'm having a hard time figuring out exactly how to subscribe to the events I need to do this instrumentation.

One thing I've tried is to get a reference to VSCode's TypeScript language features extension:

```
vscode.extensions.getExtension('vscode.typescript-language-features');
```

Unfortunately, [the API it exposes is very minimal](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/db8368395f65b584eec79e74e8d4a47aa0c60349/extensions/typescript-language-features/src/api.ts#L11) and the only thing it seems to have is `onCompletionAccepted`, which is not too helpful for me here.

I've looked through [VSCode's API events](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api) but none of them seem to quite be what I'm looking for. I think [these are the events that I need (projectLoadingStart and projectLoadingFinish), which tsserver emits internally](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/4990bd9293e6076e3c73481568c9f55ae1070f1e/lib/tsserverlibrary.d.ts#L8625-L8640), but I don't know how to listen to them. And [here I can see vscode.typescript-language-features using these events to update its loading indicator](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/f25ffb76edd1f0037da743ab4955ff7083309600/extensions/typescript-language-features/src/typescriptServiceClient.ts#L890-L896).

It seems like maybe this could be done with a [TypeScript Language Service plugin](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Writing-a-Language-Service-Plugin)? Or maybe I need to make my own TypeScript service client? Where should I start digging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're explicitly looking for the TSServer boot times, and not [general compiler perf which can be traced and measured from the CLI](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Performance).

I think the *simplest* route would to write a small tracing language service plugin with which you embed inside a VS Code extension which uses [typescriptServerPlugins](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/contribution-points#contributes.typescriptServerPlugins) which means it will be injected into all copies of the TypeScript Server. The language service plugin should receive all the same events as the main extension in VS Code - so you can measure the way they mention in that post.

It should be a generically useful tool too, so you could consider polishing it up and putting it out to the public if you get some use from it.

Comment: Do you happen to know how to access the events from inside the typescriptServerPlugin, or point me to an example of this? Is it via something on `info.project.projectService` perhaps?

Comment: Here's the start of my typescriptServerPlugin: https://gist.github.com/lencioni/e3258e3188560a88b7fffcc92fbeaf74 I've looked through a lot of stuff in tsserverlibrary, and can't find where to subscribe to the events I need. It seems like there is a Session class in there that has some stuff on it that I need, but I don't see where I can access a Session instance or subscribe to its events. Any pointers?

Comment: Alrighty, I have something that I think will work here. The main trick is to override `info.project.projectService.eventHandler` with a pass-through function. Thanks for your help! https://gist.github.com/lencioni/7031bc83a0f998b26d8b1732a17e2b98